# Reading text/strings via processing

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, serial

I'm trying to control an led attached to my arduino via key presses on my laptop.When i hold down a key, the led should light up, and when i release the key, the led should turn off.

While my code works ATM, i am wondering why my code will not work if i replace the numbers in my code with text/strings.

Processing code(Working)

```
import processing.serial.*;
Serial myPort;

void setup(){
  println("The available ports are: ");
  println(Serial.list());
  myPort = new Serial(this,Serial.list()[0],9600);
  myPort.buffer(8);
  size(500, 500);
}

void draw(){
  if(keyPressed){
    if(key == 'r' || key == 'R'){
      myPort.write(1);
      println("red");
    }

  }

}

void keyReleased(){
  myPort.write(2);println("released");
}
```

Arduino Code(Working)

```
int red = 7;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(red,OUTPUT);
}

void loop(){

}

void serialEvent(){
    int input = Serial.read();
  if(input == 1){
    digitalWrite(red,HIGH);
  }else if(input == 2){
    digitalWrite(red,LOW);
  }
}
```

Processing Code (Not working)

```
import processing.serial.*;
Serial myPort;

void setup(){
  println("The available ports are: ");
  println(Serial.list());
  myPort = new Serial(this,Serial.list()[0],9600);
  myPort.buffer(8);
  size(500, 500);
}

void draw(){
  if(keyPressed){
    if(key == 'r' || key == 'R'){
      myPort.write("red");
      println("red");
    }

  }

}

void keyReleased(){
  myPort.write("released");
  println("released");
}
```

Arduino Code(Not working)

```
int red = 7;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(red,OUTPUT);
}

void loop(){

}

void serialEvent(){
    int input = Serial.read();
  if(input == "red"){
    digitalWrite(red,HIGH);
  }else if(input == "released"){
    digitalWrite(red,LOW);
  }
}
```

From the above example, i get the error ISO C++ forbids comparisons between pointers and integers.After googling the error, it was suggested that i replace the double quotes with single quotes, after which the arduino code is able to compile, but the processing code gives an error "badly formed character constant(expecting quote,got e)".

I then tried changing using double quotes for processing and single quotes for the arduino quote, but predictably, it did not work.

Why does my code work when i pass numbers to the arduino via serial communication, and my code fails when i use text strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're mixing different variable types. It's kinda an oil/water scenario.

Basically, the `serial.read();` command returns an integer, `-1` if there's nothing in the buffer. If there is something, it will return the character code (i.e. 93 = `a`). Because of that, *it's an integer.* When you put something in single quotes, it compiles as the equivalent ISO character code.

So, when you do `input == 2`, it is `integer [compared to] integer`. When you do `input == "string"`, you're doing `integer [compared to] string`, thus you get errors. BTW: a string is a type of pointer.

So, what you have to do is this:

```
string input = "";
if(serial.avaliable()) {
    delay(100); //Wait for all data to be received
    while(serial.avaliable()) {
        string = string + char(serial.read());
    }
}
if(input == "yay_it_works!) {
    //Done!
}
```